# jQuery UI-slider changing "max" value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the jQuery UI slider for a casino game project I am working on. I need to be able to change the "max" value based upon the players current bankroll. At first, the slider works correctly, it sets the "max" slider value to 1000, the players starting bankroll. Bust as the 'currentBankroll' variable changes, the sliders "max" value does not update. I inserted a console.log() line of code to check the value of the variable 'currentBankroll', which confirms the value is changing, but the slider "max" value stays at the initial value of 1000 and does not update. To further confuse me, I tried a solution I found here to change the "max" value.

```
$('#slider-range-max2').slider("option", "max", 300);
```

This line of code will change the sliders "max" value if I put a number in it (like 300), but will not work if I use a variable (like 'currentBankroll"). How can I change the sliders value using a variable?

```
$(function() {
    console.log("Current Bankroll: " + currentBankroll);
    $("#slider-range-max2").slider({
        range: "max",
        max: 0,
        min: 1,
        max: currentBankroll,
        value: 2,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $("#amount").val( ui.value );
            sliderValue = (ui.value);
        },
        slide : function(event, ui) {
            skillLevelSlots(ui.value);
            wagerAmount = (ui.value);
            $('.wager').html("$" + wagerAmount);
        }
    });
    $('#slider-range-max2').slider("option", "max", 300);
});
```

Comment: have you tried `$('#slider-range-max2').slider("option", "max", parseInt(currentBankroll));`

Comment: You have defined the `slide` property twice, which will cause problems.

Comment: I tried the 'parseInt', but that did not work.

Comment: `var c = 5;
  $('#slider-range-min').slider("option", "max", c);`  - I just tested this in my own code and it seems to work fine. Like @RoryMcCrossan said you have `slide()` defined twice, but other than that I dont see why the code above isnt working. Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right - you are defining your slider at a certain time and using currentBankroll to set max value. This is the value when the slider is created but this doesnt change unless you re create it. To get it to change, whenever your currentBankroll changes you could  call a function that changes the value.

```
function currentBankrollChange(currentBankroll){
     $('#slider-range-max2').slider("option", "max", currentBankroll);
}
```

or when a players bankroll changes you could call:

```
 $('#slider-range-max2').slider("option", "max", currentBankroll);
```

Comment: I'm not sure where in the code to place this function, I can't seem to get it to work?

Comment: Somewhere after `$(function() {` and then whenever your code changes the currentBankroll call this function in that code - `currentBankrollChange(currentBankroll);`

Comment: or whenever a players currentBankroll changes you could just call `$('#slider-range-max2').slider("option", "max", currentBankroll);`

Comment: I tried as described, but I get an error: ReferenceError: currentBankrollChange is not defined

Comment: Okay you need to define the function before its called, so its available to be called - ie higher up in your code. try putting it in directly after `$(function(){`